# PHP Move_uploaded_file() error when trying to rename

Tags: php

The Code that I run

```
public function upload() {          
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/profilePic/" . randomString() . '.' . $fileInfo['extension']);
        return $_FILES['profilePicUpload']['name'];
    }
    function randomString($length = 128) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
    return $randomString;
```

The Error that I get when I run the code

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Picture.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Picture.php on line 11

Fatal error: Call to undefined function randomString() in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Picture.php on line 11
```

I can not find any solution so I had to post this on StackOverflow to find the solution.

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: In your function `upload()` why are you caring about `$_FILES["file"]` then suddenly returning an index into `$_FILES['profilePicUpload']`?

Answer (score 0):

If your function is part of your class, it is a class method and you need to prefix it with `$this->` or `self::` in case of a static call:

```
... "images/profilePic/" . $this->randomString() . '.' ...
```

The other errors seem pretty clear: You probably need to use `$_FILES['profilePicUpload']` consistently instead of `$_FILES["file"]`.

Answer (score 0):

from the rest of your code, it looks like you are uploading with the name "profilePicUpload" rather than "file"

replacing "file" with "profilePicUpload" should fix your issue.